# ¿Como manejar multiples sensores con Raspberry y Python?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Hola comunidad estoy realizando un proyecto con una raspberry pi, python y varios sesnores.

- Ultrasonico HC-SR04
- Rele
- LCD
- Teclado matricial

Actualmente tengo programado todos los sensores por separado, es decir cada archivo de cada sensor tiene funciones definidas, el problema que actualmente tengo es que no tengo idea de como poder manejar esos sensores al mismo tiempo o poder hacer uso de ellos, aclaro que soy un novato con python.

La primer idea que tuve fue que mediante un archivo main ejecutara las funciones pero nunca puedo hacerlas trabajar en conjunto solo se ejecuta la funcion del sensor ultrasonico (ultra).

```
#Ejemplo de mi archivo main

import sys
sys.path.append("/Keyboard/")
sys.path.append("/UltraSonico/")

import ultra
import keyboard

while True:
    ultra()
    keyboard()
```

Si alguien podría echarme una mano explicándome o dejándome alguna guía sobre un mejor control de las funciones seria de muchísima ayuda

Espero haberme explicado bien, Saludos a todos.

Comment: Bienvenido tec, te sugiero que antes que nada vayas a [tour] para saber como funcionamos y de paso ganes tu primera medalla... Después ve a [ask] y por favor edita o elimina tu pregunta según corresponda, ya que la misma está sujeta a puntuaciones negativas y reportes...

Comment: Muchas gracias @VíctorHugoTirado, e modificado algunas cosas y e tratado de eliminar lo innecesario, espero que ahora sea mejor, soy malo explicando, espero no haberme saltado nada mas. xD

Comment: Si tus funciones son bloqueantes (p.e tienen un ciclo while infinito), necesitas ejecutarlas de forma concurrente (multiprocesos/hilos/corrutinas) y de ser necesario sincronizarlos adecuadamente. Si haces lo que haces ahora no se ejecutará `keyboard` hasta que ultra `retorne`.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que te refieres es a usar varios pines de la Raspberry, puedes designar diferentes pines para cada sensor que uses,por ejemplo:

```
    sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11
    pin =4
    humedad, temperatura = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
```

En el cual ocupa una pin para el sensor, mientras que en esta parte de código usa otro pin

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(11, gpio.OUT)
```

Así juegas con los pines de la raspberry,usando las *GPIO*, pudiendo también crear un menú, espero haberte ayudado en tu duda.